# interacting with kernel modules without giving users sudo access?

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers

I'm learning how to create a kernel module in userspace. Does anyone know of any easy kernel modules that can be controlled from userspace?

I've went through /lib/modules but most of the drivers require either root access and go into esoteric functionalities, I don't really want to go through all the source code. (e.g. eepoe).

Does anyone know of any userspace kernel device driver?

[image]

Comment: Read the cited `Documentation/` [files](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation)

Answer (score 3):

The description "userspace kernel module" is a contradiction in terms: Either something runs in userspace, or it runs in the kernel, but it can't run in either, and you can't run kernel modules in userspace.

That said, it's possible to write *device drivers* in userspace, by making use of quite general kernel APIs (which run in kernel space, no matter if they are modules or not), and implementing the actual device driver functionality in userspace. Device drivers using `libusb`, `spidev` or `i2cdev` are such examples: they use a library to access well-known kernel APIs, or access the APIs directly, but the device driver logic runs in userspace.

Another, similar example is [fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace): using fixed kernel APIs, you can implement your own filesystem in userspace.

So if you want examples, google for device drivers using those APIs. But they will still be example of "user space device drivers", not "userspace kernel device drivers", so I'm not sure if this is what you want.

If you want to write something that runs in kernel space, you need to learn how to write a kernel module.

Comment: would "kernel modules that can be load/unloaded at userspace" be an accurate analogy?

Comment: That makes no sense, either: *All* kernel modules can be loaded/unloaded with commands *from* userspace (`insmod`, `rmmod`, `modprobe`). *No* kernel modules can be loaded "into" userspace, if that's what you mean by "at". A kernel module runs in kernel space, always.

Comment: the former is correct. insmod and rmmod however requires sudo access. I am looking to create a hello driver that interacts with system calls without having to give users sudo access.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I get the impression your understanding of the Linux architecture is a bit confused. "System calls" are something that userspace programs do, and processes running as any user can do that. Root just has rights to execute a few additional system calls. If you are looking for ways to run an application program that needs root rights and should be started as a non-root user, look into the `setuid` bit. That has *nothing* to do with kernel modules, or kernel space as opposed to userspace.

Comment: no problem, thank you for your feedback. I'm genuinely new at this, I should have taken the more conventional route of creating a new kernel. If its ok, please add me as a friend on gtalk or facebook, I would be happy to have a friend to discuss this with.

Answer (score 1):

There's an answer about creating files in `sysfs` on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245100/how-to-create-a-simple-sysfs-class-attribute-in-linux-kernel-v3-2). They are simple to handle and should be accessible w/o root permissions by default.